# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode

Tags: java, hibernate

estoy realizando consultas a una base de datos en [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) desde [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) utilizando Hibernate. Tengo una tabla llamadas prestamos que contiene los campos `id_libro, id_socio,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin`, la consulta es la siguiente

```
public static void consulta() {
        String c ="select id_socio from Prestamos ";
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query q= session.createQuery(c);
        List results = q.list();
        Iterator Prestamositerator = results.iterator();
        while (Prestamositerator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(Prestamositerator.next());
        }
        session.close();
    }   
}
```

El error que me da es:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode   \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'id_socio' {originalText=id_socio}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta agregando la clase Prestamos?

Comment: la base de datos será mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate está diciendo que no encuentra el atributo "id_socio" en la clase "Prestamos".

Estás utilizando lenguaje HQL, en el cual tienes que hacer referencia a las tablas usando los nombres de las clases y atributos de Java. Es decir, si tu clase Prestamos es algo parecido a esto:

```
@Table(name = "prestamos")
public class Prestamos {

//Columna id_socio en la tabla
@Column(name = "id_socio")
private int idSocio

[...]

}
```

En tu query debes utilizar el campo "idSocio" tal cual está declarado en la clase. Tu query quedaría así:

```
String c ="select idSocio from Prestamos ";
```